# Read and aggregate data from CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data file with the following format:

```
name,cost1,cost1,cost1,cost2,cost3,cost3,
X,2,4,6,5,6,8,
Y,0,3,6,5,4,6,
.
.
....
```

Now, what I would like to do is to convert this to a dictionary of dictionaries such that

```
{'X', {'cost1': 4, 'cost2':5, 'cost3':7}},{'Y', {'cost1': 3, 'cost2':5, 'cost3':5}}....
```

where the values of each key is the average from the data file. How could this be done?

Comment: Take a look at the Python [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. It has some nice examples in the documentation.

Comment: It is good to know, what you want to achieve, but you should also do your own research on the topic before you ask at StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky: I did. I just was not sure what is the most crisp way to do it! More importantly, I think this may be useful for more people out there since it is non trivial (at-least to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic version based on @cphlewis's directions:

```
load_data = csv.reader(open( "multientry.csv", "r" ))
header = next(load_data)
header = filter(bool,header)
categories = header
categories.pop(0)
categories = set(categories)
dofd={}
for row in load_data:
    row = filter(bool,tuple(value for  value in row))
    dofd[row[0]]={}
    for item in categories:
        val = [float(k) for k in [row[i+1] for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == item]]]
        dofd[row[0]][item] = sum(val)/float(len(val))
```

Comment: Cool. Did you play around with the csv.DictReader that Michael suggested above? It provides a different kind of flexibility for handling column arrangements that you don't know in advance. Longer but easy-to-read code, probably.

Comment: @cphlewis: I did not. But, the code I have presented is column arrangement independent. It will work with any ordering of the columns

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
types = [str, float, float, float, float, float, float]                                            

with open('multientry.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    headers = next(data)
    dofd = {}
    for r in data:
        r = tuple(convert(value) for convert, value in zip(types, r))
        dofd[r[0]] = {}
        dofd[r[0]]['cost1'] = (r[1]+r[2]+r[3])/3.
        dofd[r[0]]['cost2'] = r[4]
        dofd[r[0]]['cost3'] = (r[5]+r[6])/2.


print dofd
```

Comment: csv.DictReader can do the same inbuilt, without installing extra libraries.

Comment: good point @Michael! Though I didn't come up with a more readable use of DictReader's result. If the column order was unpredictable, it would be worth it, of course.

Comment: @cphlewis: Thanks. I coded a more generic version on your directions.