# Python dictionary created from CSV file should merge the value (integer) whenever the key repeats

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a file named `report_data.csv` that contains the following:

```
user,score
a,10
b,15
c,10
a,10
a,5
b,10
```

I am creating a `dictionary` from this file using this code:

```
with open('report_data.csv') as f:
   f.readline()  # Skip over the column titles
   mydict = dict(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
```

After running this code `mydict` is:

```
mydict = {'a':5,'b':10,'c':10}
```

But I want it to be:

```
mydict = {'a':25,'b':25,'c':10}
```

In other words, whenever a key that already exists in `mydict` is encountered while reading a line of the file, the new value in `mydict` associated with that key should be the sum of the old value and the integer that appears on that line of the file. How can I do this?

Comment: There are lots of previous questions about aggregating data from a CSV in Python [ [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17430553/478288), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17526777/478288), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8800111/478288), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23319989/478288) ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use `defaultdict` or `Counter` from useful [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

```
from collections import Counter
summary = Counter()
with open('report_data.csv') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        lbl, n = line.split(",")
        n = int(n)
        summary[lbl] = summary[lbl] + n
```

One of the most useful features in `Counter` class is the `most_common()` function, that is absent from the plain dictionaries and from  `defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
with open('report_data.csv') as f:
  f.readline()
  mydict = {}
  for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    mydict[line[0]] = mydict.get(line[0], 0) + int(line[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
mydict = {}
with open('report_data.csv') as f:
    f.readline()
    x = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for x1 in x:
        if mydict.get(x1[0]):
            mydict[x1[0]] += int(x1[1])
        else:
            mydict[x1[0]] = int(x1[1])
print mydict
```